# Azure Blob Storage REST API - 403 Server failed to authenticate the request

Tags: postman, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to send a request from Postman to upload a file to azure blob storage. But, as much as I have tried I have not been able to authenticate the request, I have reviewed the official documentation and several posts here on Stack Overflow without success in creating the signature.

the configuration of headers in postman

[postman headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jfk4.png)

I am using the pre-script request option to generate the signature.

```
const crypto = require('crypto-js');

const date = new Date().toUTCString();

const method = "PUT";
const containerName = "media";
const x_ms_version = "2015-12-11";
const accountName = "revistaregion";
const blobName = "revista-region-original.png";
const accountKey = "olOuS5cG....................";

const xmsHeader = `x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:${date}\nx-ms-version:${x_ms_version}`;
const resHeader = `/${containerName}/${blobName}`;


const stringToSign = method + "\n" +
            "\n" + //Content Encoding
            "\n" + //Content Language
            "717\n" + //Content Length
            "\n" + //Content MD5
            "image/png\n" + //Content Type
            "\n" + //Date
            "\n" + //If - Modified - Since
            "\n" + //If - Match
            "\n" + //If - None - Match
            "\n" + //If - Unmodified - Since
            "\n" + //Range +
           xmsHeader +
           resHeader;


const signature = crypto.HmacSHA256(crypto.enc.Utf8.parse(stringToSign), crypto.enc.Base64.parse(accountKey));
const signatureBase64 = crypto.enc.Base64.stringify(signature);

const authorizationHeader = `SharedKey ${accountName}:${signatureBase64}`;

pm.environment.set("authorizationHeader", authorizationHeader)
pm.environment.set("time", date)
```

the response to the petition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:97e7b328-001e-0001-14f0-471dd1000000
Time:2024-01-15T20:24:11.2993548Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'WPGDEOMEQ06F7L9Nhog3BwuIRZMFRnOVEalDOLMf3yI=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT


717

image/png






x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob
x-ms-date:Mon, 15 Jan 2024 20:24:10 GMT
x-ms-version:2015-12-11
/revistaregion/media/revista-region-original.png'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Venkatesan

Compared to the correct answer there is a difference in the resHeader.

My code:

```
const resHeader = `/${containerName}/${blobName}`;
```

The one in the correct answer:

```
const resHeader = `/${accountName}/${containerName}/${blobName}`;
```

Also, I have added the headers: **Content-type** and **Content-Length** in Postman.

As I followed the signature construction (**stringToSign**) as shown in the correct answer.

Comment: Check the below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Although I still don't know why it doesn't work with Postman.

You can use the same code to create an Authorization header, date and time.

**Code:**

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

const account = "venkat789";
const key = "xxxx";
const strTime = new Date().toUTCString();

const string_params = {
   'verb': 'PUT',
   'Content-Encoding': '',
   'Content-Language': '',
   'Content-Length': '18063',
   'Content-MD5': '',
   'Content-Type': 'image/png',
   'Date': '',
   'If-Modified-Since': '',
   'If-Match': '',
   'If-None-Match': '',
   'If-Unmodified-Since': '',
   'Range': '',
   'CanonicalizedHeaders': `x-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:${strTime}\nx-ms-version:2020-04-08\n`,
   'CanonicalizedResource': `/${account}/demo/sample.png`
};

const strToSign = `${string_params['verb']}\n${string_params['Content-Encoding']}\n${string_params['Content-Language']}\n${string_params['Content-Length']}\n${string_params['Content-MD5']}\n${string_params['Content-Type']}\n${string_params['Date']}\n${string_params['If-Modified-Since']}\n${string_params['If-Match']}\n${string_params['If-None-Match']}\n${string_params['If-Unmodified-Since']}\n${string_params['Range']}\n${string_params['CanonicalizedHeaders']}${string_params['CanonicalizedResource']}`;

const secret = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
const hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(strToSign, secret);
const hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
const auth = `SharedKey ${account}:${hashInBase64}`;

console.log(auth);
console.log(strTime)
```

**Output:**

```
SharedKey venkat789:zHfjZJnxxxxx
Tue, 16 Jan 2024 05:25:14 GMT
```

[image]

**Postman:**

You can use the request below to upload a file to Azure blob storage using Postman.

```
PUT https://venkat789.blob.core.windows.net/demo/sample.png
Headers:
"x-ms-blob-type": 'BlockBlob',
"x-ms-date": "Tue, 16 Jan 2024 05:25:14 GMT",
"x-ms-version": "2020-04-08",
"Content-Type": "image/png",
"Content-Length": 18063
"Authorization": SharedKey venkat789:kAX8d1bRxxx 
body:<Binary format of file>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Authorize with Shared Key (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have compared the code I have in Postman with the one in your answer and I have noticed differences that I will update in the publication. Again thank you very much @Venkatesan

Comment: Glad to know that it worked.